# Can I ignore multicolinearity problem if all the regression coefficients are highly significant?

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, regression-analysis

Can I ignore multicolinearity problem if all the regression coefficients are highly significant?

My data is large enough and all the resulting coefficients are significant enough in less than 0.01 level. 
The only thing I see is that one of the variable has the correlation of 0.9.

Can I keep this variable?

Comment: Might be a question for stats SE (crossvalidated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant that a $\textit{pair}$ of independent variables are highly correlated ($0.9$). Basically, although technically it's fine, this may indicate that both variables measure (almost) the same factor. Hence, generally speaking, bring the same information to the model, as such may cause redundancy. The fact that both variables are significant may be an artifact of the very large data set that you have. This is due to the fact that p.values are (generally) a monotone non decreasing (in most cases, strictly increasing) functions of the sample size.

Perhaps, if you want to keep both variables, you should consider to build one single index out of them.

Comment: Thanks. What if I am using only the final output from the logistic regression? Can't I ignore the multicolinearity issue in this case then?

Comment: It is rather statistical question than mathematical. Namely, mathematically, as far as you don't have complete multicolinearity ($1$), you will get estimators that maximize the appropriate function (Likelihood in most cases). Statistically it may cause some problems of stability and efficacy. But, generally, if you are interested only in the point estimator of the probability (i.e., point predictions), it  maybe OK to ignore these issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great comment! It helps indeed!